# How to light virtual objects in panorama image with light positions

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia, arcore

In a panorama image, I have the light positions. How to light virtual objects like sphere and rabbits?

I have tried estimating distance but the result is poor. Vuforia 
does not give any option for me.

I plan to make it at pc first. Should I use environment map?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `intensity` and `range` of the [Light](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light.html).

Try using this :

```
Light lt;

void Start()
{
    lt = GetComponent<Light>();
    lt.range=50.60f;
    lt.intensity=0.8f;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely try it.

Comment: My current code does not allow me to match with that interface. i found python with the pygame and pyglut libraries. Can I achieve the same thing? Thanks.